# Is there a tmux shortcut to create a new session?

Tags: tmux

Just like **leader_key + C** creates a new window inside a session. Is there a similar shortcut for  creating a new session ?
Currently, I use **leader_key + new**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no predefined shortcuts, the only native way to do it is :

- Create session: `tmux new -s session_name`
- `Ctrl-B + d to detach`
- Return to your session: `tmux attach-session -t session_name`

Comment: Doing it from the command prompt is easier than detaching: `C-b : new`.

Answer (score 12):

Why not just create a keybinding for that in your `.tmux.conf`?

These two settings let you create/kill a new session when pressing `Prefix S (Shift+s)` or `Prefix K (Shift+k)` respectively:

```
bind S command-prompt -p "New Session:" "new-session -A -s '%%'"
bind K confirm kill-session
```

`Prefix Shift+s` will open a command prompt in the status line, asking for a new session name. It will either create a new session with that name or attach to an already existing session by that name.

Answer (score 5):

From inside tmux you can just do

1. `ctrl+B`
2. then write `:new<enter>`

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now but I was looking for a shortcut

Comment: There is no built in keyboard shortcut. But it is easy to create if that is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can create this keybinding in the `.tmux.config`:

```
bind-key L command-prompt -p "Enter session name:" "new-session -s '%%'"
bind-key C command-prompt -p "Enter window name:" "new-window -n '%%'"
```